# Multiple MVC projects to publish on single domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm looking way to publish two different MVC projects under the same domain.

I would like to create a content management system and an user interface with different projects.

**project 1:** domain.com/cms/

**project 2:** domain.com/

Is that possible and how?

Thanks.